# Crashes after changing the data in the combo box

Tags: python, pyqt5

My app works fine when I select the country and city for the first time, but after I change the country my app crashes. I want to implement a change system in the lists so that I can quickly change the country or city.

changed the code

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QComboBox, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from yaweather import YaWeather, cities


class WeatherApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Weather App')
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 300, 200)

        # Create a label to display the weather
        self.weather_label = QLabel()
        self.weather_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        # Connect to the yandex weather API
        self.ywm = YaWeather(api_key='')

        self.create_cb_countries()
        self.create_cb_cities()

        # Create a layout and add the widgets to it
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.countries_combo)
        layout.addWidget(self.cities_combo)
        layout.addWidget(self.weather_label)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def country_changed(self):
        country = self.countries_combo.currentText()
        self.weather_label.setText(country)
        self.cities_combo.setEnabled(True)
        country_class = getattr(cities, country)
        self.populate_cities_combo(country_class)

    def city_changed(self):
        city = self.cities_combo.currentText()
        country = self.countries_combo.currentText()
        country_class = getattr(cities, country)
        coordinates = country_class.cities()[city]
        self.update_weather(coordinates)

    def update_weather(self, coordinates):
        res = self.ywm.forecast(coordinates)
        weather_string = f'Now: {res.fact.temp} °C, feels like {res.fact.feels_like} °C'
        self.weather_label.setText(weather_string)

    def create_cb_countries(self):
        self.countries_combo = QComboBox()
        countries = [c.name() for c in cities.CountryBase.__subclasses__()]
        self.countries_combo.addItems(countries)
        self.countries_combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.country_changed)

    def create_cb_cities(self):
        self.cities_combo = QComboBox()
        self.cities_combo.setEnabled(False)
        self.cities_combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.city_changed)

    def populate_cities_combo(self, country_class):
        self.cities_combo.clear()
        cities_ = country_class.cities()
        self.cities_combo.addItems(cities_.keys())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    weather_app = WeatherApp()
    weather_app.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried to overwrite the second field but it does not help

[image: Flies out here]

add traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\application.py", line 41, in city_changed
    coordinates = country_class.cities()[city]
```

Comment: remove the api key from your post

Comment: What is the error? Any trace?

Comment: @jlandercy, when you change the field already with the selected country, the program crashes

Comment: He meant: what is the error printed in the terminal, if any?

Comment: @jlandercy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  , line 41, in city_changed
    coordinates = country_class.cities()[city]

Comment: Are you sure you copied the entire error? Also include it in your question so other people can see it without having to dig in the comments

Comment: I get also KeyError: ' ' and that's it, there are still path files there, but there is no need

Comment: This means that `city`, in line 41, is equal to `''`. See [how-to-fix-keyerror](https://rollbar.com/blog/python-keyerror/)

Answer (score 1):

If you change the country, the city is for a glitch not set (empty string). You could ignore that in `city_changed` or fix the update cycle.

```
    def city_changed(self):
        city = self.cities_combo.currentText()
        if not city:
            return
        country = self.countries_combo.currentText()
        country_class = getattr(cities, country)
        coordinates = country_class.cities()[city]
        self.update_weather(coordinates)
```